# Which preposition should I use with "consultation" to express relation with a "topic"

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to describe an act of consulting some topic and have touble figuring out the right preposition.

My "gut" candidates are:

> 1. *topic* consultation
> 2. consultation **about** *topic*
> 3. consultation **over** *topic* (similar to discussing)
> 4. consultation **on** *topic*

Or is it something else? I look for a noun, something like "I've had a very informative consultation on/over/about *topic* with Bob."

I know it can be rephrased using a verb form, but I feel that e.g. for a title, or something similar a noun form looks better.

Embarrassingly I could not find an example of such usage in any dictionary. Maybe it's not correct at all.

Comment: Why don't you use the verb "consult"?

Comment: I think it sounds awkward and you haven't been able to find a usage example because we just don't usually say "consultation on/over/about *topic*"  [If you look at the Google Ngrams result, it looks like the most common one is "consultation on"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consultation+*&year_start=1900&year_end=2000), but even that's not very common.  It sounds more fluent to say "I consulted Bob about *topic*" or "a meeting with Bob about *topic*" or "a discussion with Bob on *topic*."

Comment: Note that the relatively formal term ***consultation*** usually implies [***a meeting with an expert**, such as a medical doctor, in order **to seek advice***](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jZ52V8u4Me3R8geOxbyIBg#q=define+consultation). If the meeting isn't particularly formal, or it's more of a ***two-way exchange*** of opinions, it would be much better to say *I consulted with Bob [about / over / on / regarding / etc. some topic]*.

Answer (score 2):

Synthesizing some of the comments - the verb "to consult" is much more commonly used and sounds much more natural.  As FumbleFingers says, there is a formal sense of the word consultation which does come up.  In this case I would agree that of the options, a "consultation on" sounds the best.  Somewhat more formally, you could also say a "consultation regarding some topic".

Answer (score 1):

I would use consultation on. Have a look at this one: 
http://youglish.com/search/%22consultation%20on%22

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice to summarize the link though, in case the reference disappears.

Answer (score 0):

From Cambridge Dictionary:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consultation
consultation with sb They adopted the rules this summer after months of consultation with their lawyers.
consultation on sth The consultation on these options showed that Option 1 was widely rejected.
consultation document/paper He has laid out his concerns in a consultation paper.
consultation period/process The consultation period for the bill is just two weeks.
in consultation with sb The director will make his decision in consultation with his advisors.